# Let L1={a^nb^mc^(n+m) / n,m > 0} and L2={a^nb^nc^m / n,m > 0}.Is L3= L1 ∩ L2 context-free or not?

Tags: algorithm, computation-theory

Let L1={a^n b^m c^(n+m) / n,m > 0} and L2={a^n b^n c^m / n,m > 0}.Is L3= L1 ∩ L2 context-free or not?

My logic being is if n < m the intersection will yield a language (a^n b^n c^n) if n > m the intersection will yield a language (a^n b^m c^m) in both cases we have a CFG so is my interpretation correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about theoretical computer science, and not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understood your idea correctly, but if you try using the same n and m for both L1 and L2 and compute the intersection based on that, you are not right.

Besides that, the language {*a*<sup>n</sup> *b*<sup>n</sup> *c*<sup>n</sup> | n > 0} is not CFG, as you can see as an example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language or show by using the pumping lemma.

How can one see what L1 ∩ L2 looks like?
x ∈ L1 ∩ L2 <=> x ∈ L1 and x ∈ L2. So x must fullfill both restrictions of the two languages.
Therefore x ∈ L1 ∩ L2 is x = *a*<sup>n</sup> *b*<sup>m</sup> *c*<sup>o</sup> where n = m because of L2 and o = n+m = n+n (n + m because of L1 and n + n because n = m).
This gives us L1 ∩ L2 = {*a*<sup>n</sup> *b*<sup>n</sup> *c*<sup>2n</sup> | n > 0}, which is not CFG.

Reason:

- Intuitively speaking a CFG can not count (more than once, *a*<sup>n</sup> *b*<sup>n</sup> is fine). But for achieving the pattern n, n, 2n, we have to count the amoung of a and b and then add the right amount of c.
- Pumping Lemma: We have to negate the original lemma in order to show that {*a*<sup>n</sup> *b*<sup>n</sup> *c*<sup>2n</sup> | n > 0} is not CFG. So we need to prove that for every p >= 0 there is a s ∈ {*a*<sup>n</sup> *b*<sup>n</sup> *c*<sup>2n</sup> | n > 0} which can NOT be split into uvwxy fullfilling |uvw| <= p and u*v*<sup>k</sup>w*x*<sup>k</sup>y ∈ {*a*<sup>n</sup> *b*<sup>n</sup> *c*<sup>2n</sup> | n > 0}.
  Proof: Given a p >= 0. We choose the word *t* = *a*<sup>p</sup> *b*<sup>p</sup> *c*<sup>2p</sup> ∈ L1 ∩ L2. Now for every choose of *uvwxy = t* we can not pump *uvwxy* to still be ∈ L1 ∩ L2. This is because we only pump *v* and *x*. And |vwx| is <= p. So *vwx* can not contain a, b, and c but at max two of them. Now if we pump *v* and *x* we get more a than c, or the other way round and the result u*v*<sup>2</sup>w*x*<sup>2</sup>y is not in L1 ∩ L2.